# Not able to setup SKIP tools in Mac

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cross-platform

Trying to run skip command under corporate proxy from the terminal, getting below errors.

But we able to access same url in browser
https://source.skip.tools/skip/releases/download/0.7.16/skip.zip

**command**: brew install skiptools/skip/skip

**Error**:

Installing skip means you have AGREED to the license at:
https://skip.tools/eula

==> Downloading https://source.skip.tools/skip/releases/download/0.7.16/skip.zip
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: source.skip.tools

What could be the reason for the above errors?